# How can I round the corners of a QPushButton using style sheet?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have a `QPushButton`, and I have tried to change its style: color, shape etc...

I used something like this:

```
button->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("QPushButton{background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
  "stop: 0 white, stop: 1 grey);"
  "border-style: solid;"
  "border-width: 2px;"
  "border-color: black;"
  "border-radius: 15px;}"));
```

But I get a button that has rounded borders, with a background that is not rounded, so it goes out of view.

I have tried padding, but it doesn't work. A small padding does nothing, and a big one hides the background.

I have a widget window with expanded `QGraphicsView` (created in Designer). Using code, I created `QGrapchisScene`. Then I added a pixmap and my buttons (class Button inherits `QPushButton`) to that scene, and I get something like this:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I use this CSS, and it works for me.

Don't use the pixmap, use it from the CSS directly as specified here: [QPushButton and images](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

I have to use pixmap, because it is background of whole window, not button.
And I solved my problem: I change some things, and I should set qGraphicsView as a parent of button, and only then it works fine.